Fourier coefficients on $\mathbb{T}^n$
Let $f\in C^k(\mathbb{T}^n)$ and define its Fourier series by $\sum_{\nu\in\mathbb{Z}^n} \hat{f}(\nu)e^{i\nu x}$ with the coefficients $\hat{f}(\nu)=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{T}^n}f(x)e^{-i\nu x} dx$. I want to show that $$ \hat{f}(\nu)=\left(\frac{1}{i\nu_j}\right)^k \hat{f_j}(v), $$ where $f_j(v):=\partial_j^kf$. I see that I should get this by integration by parts, but I don't know how to write it correctly for integration over the torus. How do I do this?
Thanks for your help.

Integration on the Torus is integration over $[-\pi, \pi]^d$.

@Kakashi. Do I then integrate by parts in each coordinate?

Over the $j$th coordinate, to introduce one $\partial_j$ derivative on $f$
